# Understanding the OSI Model

Tags: wireless, communication, protocol, standard, modeling

I'm currently documenting a wireless, microcontroller-based system that I've built and I would like to use the standard industry terminology to help anyone who comes behind me comprehend it easier.  It seems like the [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) for describing communications systems in terms of abstraction is the standard model.  I would like to understand the layers a little deeper, but all the examples I can find use the [Internet Protocol Suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) (TCP/IP) as their example case.  Depending on who you read, the TCP/IP only uses a subset (anywhere between 3-7 layers) which makes it somewhat harder to understand due to the lack of implementation of layers & differences in classification of layers between sources.  I don't just want to read the OSI spec as that seems too detailed, and the usual Wikipedia research doesn't seem to clear it up completely for me either.  Can anyone explain, in general, what parts of communications system are included in each abstraction layer?  Do these layers build on one another, or are some of them completely parallel?

Comment: I removed your last sentence as the goal of this site is to be the source of the information, not just a bunch of links to other sites. However, I think this question may be border line off-topic. We do cover some communication systems, but there is a chance another site might be a better fit. I am leaving it as is for now though to see what others think.

Comment: @Kellenjb - Thanks & good call! I'm going to edit a little more to clarify now that you've corrected it a bit.

Comment: Are you seriously asking us to explain the OSI layers, but at the same time you deem the internet resources like this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description_of_OSI_layers) inadequate? If you have anything specific you don't understand I'd be happy to clarify, but I am not gona duplicate that wiki or write a texbook...

Comment: I think the question is off topic and should be migrated to a networking or unix stack. Probably best match is serverfault.

Comment: Unless you have specific questions about a hardware-touching layer, this isn't a electrical engineering problem.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen - Originally I asked for other references that would be more helpful in understanding this that weren't Wikipedia (I was hoping for books, websites, diagrams, etc), but Kellenjb (I believe correctly) edited the post to ask for an explanation here as "the goal of this site is to be the source of the information". I agree that the Wiki site has **a lot** of information, but it's harder to digest & there isn't a full breakdown of an actual piece of hardware, so if someone here could give a rough description of each abstraction layer, that seemed in the scope of this site.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - The [faq] states that questions about "a communication scheme" are on topic here. How is a question about the standard model used to describe communications schemes not on topic here?

Comment: Instead of musing that the OSI model *might* describe your system, perhaps you'd do better here by giving some details of your system and just asking for help with the terminology.

Comment: It is not so much that we don't *want* to answer the question because we think it is off topic, it is more about this particular subject having more people with in depth knowledge in one of the other stacks (like serverfault).

Comment: @JoelB: The wiki I referenced seems very clear to me. What questions do you still have after reading it?

Comment: I liken OSI model to discussions of string theory. It is helpful to understand the layers of communication as it is to imagine the physics of nature, but I do not know anyone who uses the OSI model to design a network nor has String Theory predicted anything about nature. Nevertheless it is useful for "discussing unique" observed properties in both cases. I agree these set of questions are beyond the scope of Electronics Engineering and recommend moving to the abstract Network discussion group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe OSI model is very idealistic and deals with the hierarchical relationship between layers in the **protocol stack**. The interdependencies may be uniquely defined for **any** application, as they will differ from each other as it might on any operating system.  The  7 layers were shown visually in a pyramid to define that each layer was dependant on all the layers below it as dependants and all the layers above layers as precedents.

These interdependencies for each application when understood, become a knowledgebase for cause and effect. This relationship can often be measured statistically for correlation with overall performance or use by ITIL support staff for troubleshooting. Isolating the root causes of a problem requires symptoms with previous experimental results and correlation to present symptoms and experiments.

**Q**  Do these layers build on one another, or are some of them completely parallel?

**A** Yes. For most applications they lay the foundation for each layer, but in some cases may run as infrastructure layers to support the above layer.